# What is a "15-hit kiss"?

Tags: assassination-classroom

In *Assassination Classroom*, season 2 episode 15, we see Nagisa Shiota perform a "15-hit kiss" on Kaede Kayano (aka Akari Yukimura) to help save her life. Afterward, everyone is amazed that Nagisa performed a 15-hit kiss, but what is a "#-hit kiss" and what does the number symbolize?

[image: A screenshot of the "15-hit kiss"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The #-hit kiss is a technique first seen in action by Irina Jelavić in chapter 8 ("Breast Time") in the manga (page 17), or episode 4 ("Adult Time") in the anime (6.5 minutes in), when she kisses Nagisa for a 30-hit kiss.

[image: Irina kissing Nagisa]

<sup>[*See full-size image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er8vN.jpg)</sup>

It is described by Nagisa in the manga:

> I truly felt the weight of her "killing" words and that she was the real deal, a professional hitman. A kiss so incredible that it overpowers the senses. It could bring even the strongest men to their knees.

So this kiss is a weapon for seduction and assassination, and Nagisa recognizes its power. This is the reason he knows how to use it on Kaede Kayano later. It's because he experienced it first-hand by Irina.

The hit count is, as a [comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36037/what-is-a-15-hit-kiss/38621#comment48420_36037) mentioned, probably a reference to [combo hits in videogames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_(video_gaming)). From Wikipedia:

> The first game to count the hits of each combo, and reward the player for performing them, was Super Street Fighter II.